# 5G: Mapping QoS flow to a DRB requiring out-of-order delivery

Tags: qos, 5g

I understand that 5GNR allows out-of-order delivery for some DRBs by configuring them as such. Also, I understand that a QoS Flow is mapped by SDAP to a DRB based on QoS parameters provided from the core network. However, its not clear to me if there is any information (in an IE during QoS flow setup or otherwise) provided by the core network that informs the gNB to map a particular flow to a DRB that allows out-of-order delivery. If not, how does the gNB perform such mapping ?

Comment: *Requiring* out-of-order delivery??

Comment: "Requiring" or "reccomending"

Comment: *Requiring* or even *recommending* are both extremely weird. *Allow* or *deal with* is very different.